# Exclude specific attributes for machine learning prediction (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to predict daily fantasy score of NBA players. I have the stats from a 2015-2016 NBA season for each player into csv files. The problem is that when I try to predict the daily fantasy score at a specific date, it takes into account the stats that the player produced that date.
My goal is to predict,for example, the daily fantasy points at 2/2/2016 and take into consideration all the available data before 2/2/2016.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math, datetime, time
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn import preprocessing,cross_validation, svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style


filename = 'book2.CSV'
names = ['FG', 'FGA', 'FG%', '3P', '3PA', 'FTA', 'FT%', 'ORB', 'DRB', 'TRB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF', 'PTS', 'DFS']
df = pandas.read_csv(filename, names=names)

print(df.head())
style.use('ggplot')

forecast_col = 'DFS'

#forecast_out= int(math.ceil (0.1*len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col]

X = np.array(df.drop(['label','DFS'],1))
#X = preprocessing.scale(X)
#X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
#X = X[-forecast_out:]






#X = np.array(df.drop(['label','DFS'],1))


df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df['label'])

train_size = 30
svr = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1), cv=5,
                   param_grid={"C": [1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3],
                               "gamma": np.logspace(-2, 2, 5)})


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
svr.fit(X[:train_size], y[:train_size])

accuracy=clf.score(X_test,y_test)

print(accuracy)

svr.predict= y

forecast_set = clf.predict(X)

print(forecast_set)

df['DFS'].plot()
df['label'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```

My csv files look like this:

3,8,0.375,0,2,3,3,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,1,9,10.8

3,6,0.5,0,2,0,2,0,4,4,0,0,0,2,1,6,10

8,15,0.533,0,3,3,4,0,2,2,2,1,0,1,3,19,26

Each line is the stat line of a player at a specific date ( first line is the stats from 1/2/2016, second line the stats from 2/2/2016 etc).
My target is the last number at each line (the daily fantasy score). To predict this I want to take into consideration only the numbers from the line above. So if I want to predict "26" I want to use :

3,8,0.375,0,2,3,3,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,1,9,10.8

3,6,0.5,0,2,0,2,0,4,4,0,0,0,2,1,6,10